# How to trigger onPress in button tag embedded in TouchableOpacity tag without triggering onPress in TouchableOpacity

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a view that stays hidden until the expand state is true. it is set to !expand in toggleView when TouchableOpacity is pressed. However, when i click on the buttons to add to cart & delete the view is also toggled.
How can i prevent that from happening?

```
return (
    <View style={styles.accordion}>
        {/* Visible Bar which is pressed to expand hidden view */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleView} style={styles.collapsibleBar}>
            <Icon name={expanded ? 'chevron-down-outline' : 'chevron-right-outline'} pack='eva' fill='grey' style={styles.icon} />
        <View style={styles.itemHeader}>
            <View style={styles.itemHeaderTextView}>
                {/* HEADER STUFF */}
            </View>

            <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                 <Button onPress={() => addToCart()}>
                Add to Cart
                   </Button>
                <Button onPress={() => delete()}>
                delete
                   </Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* Hidden View */}
        <View style={{ maxHeight: height, width: '100%', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
            <>
            {console.log(expanded)}
            {expanded && ExpandedChild({
                setHeight: setHeight,
                date: props.cargoCharge.storageDueDate, tableData: props.cargoCharge.charges
            })}
            </>
        </View>
    </View>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this might be occurring for someone else,

This issue was happening because *TouchableOpacity* was being imported from *"react-native-gesture-handler"* in stead of *"react-native"*

so all i needed to do was replace :

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

with

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace internal buttons with 2 `TouchableOpacity` like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pk3k23w4y0?file=/src/App.js). If you click on internal `TouchableOpacity`, event will be not propagated to the external `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: It still propagated when i did that, even when i took the exact code from the  linked and rendered it. Then i placed the linked code in the parent for this code and it worked. This functional component is being rendered inside a flatList as a listItem, do you think that is a factor?

Comment: I don't think that `FlatList` is involved. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flatlist-issue-rn-web-1q5ud) an example of nested `TouchableOpacity` in `FlatList`. If you want, try to make a codesandbox to reproduce this behavior so we can see and work on the same code.

Comment: I recreated the issue, but by doing so i found the solution, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/touchopacity-propagation-problem-8bi0x). it was something that was overlooked. appreciated the guidance @Giovanni Esposito

Comment: Very well! Happy to ear that you found a solution. Have a nice day :)